# Unit tests for Project Using Z3

Tags: c#, unit-testing, z3

I have a project in c# which makes use of the Z3 library. The project runs and works perfectly fine on its own. But I try to add a second project to the main solution, and use the second project as a Unit testing project for the first and main project. In the second project I add reference to the first project and I also install NUnit from the "Manage NuGet packages...". But after I have built the whole solution and try to run the unit tests I get a error message saying:

System.BadImageFormatException : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Z3, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9c8d792caae602a2' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you may be trying to use a 64-bit DLL from a 32-bit program. Make sure the configuration is set to the same bitness in the two projects.

Comment: You are right, but for my unit test I have added a project to the current solution of type class library. Where do I set that this unit test project should be 64 bit?

Comment: In the project properties and the and the configuration manager!